# button listener doesn't response on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Now i know people have already asked this question many times before, and i read all of these posts:

[NullPointerException with Fragment Interface Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034733/nullpointerexception-with-fragment-interface-listener)

[Click listener inside a fragmentactivity with Page Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923144/click-listener-inside-a-fragmentactivity-with-page-adapter)

[button inside a fragment doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588972/button-inside-a-fragment-doesnt-work)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286220/my-button-action-is-not-working-in-tabs-view-using-fragments

[button inside a fragment doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588972/button-inside-a-fragment-doesnt-work)

[findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android)

and still i don't know how to make this simple code work. 
So i created a **viewpager** with 2 fragments, in fragment **A** there is a button and every time i click on it the **onClickListener** is not preformed and there is no exceptions.

Fragment activity java

```
public class Asec extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager vp = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_asec);
        vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        vp.setAdapter(new ma(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }
}

class ma extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ma(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment a = null;
        if (arg0 == 0) {
            a = new A();
        }
        if (arg0 == 1) {
            a = new b();
        }
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Fragment activity xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">           
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Fragment A java

```
public class A extends Fragment{
    Button b;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.av, container, false);//this is line A
        b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);//this is line B
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("work");//this is not printed

            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.av, container, false);
    }

}
```

I tried alternative way for line A like **getView().findViewById(...)** and it is still not working

Fragment A xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#33D692">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Fragment A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment B java (from now on, not really important)

```
public class b extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bv, container, false);
    }


}
```

Fragment B xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F53636" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Fragment B"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i know there is lot of questions like this and i actually read all of them and non of the answers were really helpful.
thanx for commenting this post.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use an Activity, and change some code. The XML file could be like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">   

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="logical.address.of.your.Fragment"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And you change your Activity class in this way:

```
mActionFragment = (ClassA)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_a);
```

I hope that it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment you're inflating a layout twice:

```
View view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.av, container, false);//this is line A
//...
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.av, container, false);
```

The layout you've set your click listener on is not the same that's displayed on screen.

Return the `view` you inflated and set click listener on and don't inflate another layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps anymore, but:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("work");//this is not printed

}
```

This won't work because `System.out.println("")` doesn't work in Android. Use `Log.d(tag, message)` for debug messages or `Log.e(tag, message)` for errors instead.